# PgUp/PgDn functioning intermittently

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, dell-latitude

This one puzzles me. PgUp and PgDn regularly stop functioning on this laptop (Dell Latitude 7400 with Win10, 2 years old and otherwise in good physical condition).

I'd immediately suspect a hardware issue, however there also regularly are periods where these two work just fine (like right now). For as far as I can tell I haven't installed anything that intercepts or alters keystrokes, and it doesn't seem like a StickyKeys issue (I disable that every time I get a new laptop or OS). Sometimes pressing one of them for a while seems to get them going again (although sometimes also not), and if one works, both do, and if one doesn't, neither do.

Before I raise a support ticket and go into a lengthy keyboard replacement process, are there any **OS** or **software** related causes for this, that I may have overlooked? Any further diagnostic suggestions are also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Try a USB keyboard and see it hat works.

Comment: Yep, that works. Sometimes you need someone to tell you to "keep it simple, stupid" :)

Comment: I posted an answer for you and I trust you will accept it.

Comment: There you go. Why didn't you post this directly as an answer in the first place?

Comment: Why didn't you post this directly as an answer in the first place?  .... It is possible for there to be other errors, so it is worth exploring first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any further diagnostic suggestions are also welcome. Thanks!

Try a USB keyboard and see it that works.  Assuming so, then that means the laptop keyboard needs replacing.